# Icons In ListView

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am trying to add icons next to text in a listview, but I keep getting an error saying I need to **imagelist must be initialised before it can be used**.

On the form window as it loads, I have the following code:

```
    Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ImageList3.ListImages.Add Key:="Koala", Picture:=LoadPicture("\images\add_icon.gif")
    end sub
```

Then I am trying to populate the listview like this

```
li.ListSubItems.Add , , "Test", "Koala"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to link your ImageList to the ListView using the `Icons`-property. Add the following line in the `UserForm_Initialize` - this must be done before you populate the ListView (of course you need to adapt the name of the ListView)

```
Me.ListView1.Icons = ImageList3
```